# get key from Map<String,List<String>> knowing one of the List values

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart

I have a map

```
Map<String, List> map1 = {a: [1,2,3,4], b: [5,6,7,8], c: [9,10,11]};
```

I know one of the values of one of the lists - 1..11.
How can I get the key of a map entity where this value belongs to - a, b, c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, where `search` is the value you're trying to find in the array.

Note that `firstWhere` can give you an error if the value cannot be found anywhere.

```
void main() {
  final data = {
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'b': [5, 6, 7, 8],
    'c': [9, 10, 11]
  };

  final search = 4;

  final selected = data.keys.firstWhere((key) {
    return data[key]!.contains(search);
  });

  print(selected); // a
}
```

Comment: yeah, actually I found the same solution and we've posted answers the same time jaja... anyway, will mark your reply as the solution. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
int valueToLookFor = 5;

String keyName = map1.keys.firstWhere((key) => map1[key]!.contains(valueToLookFor));
```